# Change onmouseout to the color of another element

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, calendar

I have an asp:Calendar in a C# web app:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cal_ReserveDate" runat="server"
                            DayStyle-ForeColor="DarkBlue" DayHeaderStyle-BackColor="#FEF6CB" DayStyle-Height="25" DayStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                            SelectedDayStyle-BackColor="#003F7D" SelectedDayStyle-ForeColor="White"
                            DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" ShowGridLines="true" BorderColor="Black"
                            TitleStyle-BackColor="#003F7D" TitleStyle-ForeColor="White" TitleStyle-CssClass="CalHeader"
                            NextPrevStyle-CssClass="CalNextPrev" NextPrevStyle-ForeColor="White"
                            OnVisibleMonthChanged="cal_ReserveDate_VisibleMonthChanged"
                            OnDayRender="cal_ReserveDate_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="cal_ReserveDate_SelectionChanged"
                            DayStyle-BorderColor="Black" SelectedDayStyle-CssClass="CalendarSelectedDay" Width="97%" Font-Bold="true" />
```

I am using the `OnDayRender` to adjust colors for closed, sold out, etc. dates.  I want to make today a color our design team can set from the style sheet.  I added this to the style for starters, but it could grow:

```
.calendarToday {
    background-color: mistyrose;   
}
```

In my code when I render "today" I have this:

```
if (e.Day.IsToday)
{                
    string onmouseoutStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='@BackColor'";    
    e.Cell.CssClass = "calendarToday";   
    e.Cell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle.Replace("@BackColor", <<read current bgColor>>));
}
```

This is similar to the code I have in the sold-out day, for example, to reset the background at mouse-out, but it is all fixed predefined colors hard coded into the app everywhere else.

What I'm trying to do is set the `onmouseout` to whatever background color is defined in the `calendarToday` style but I don't know how to access the `e.Cell` attributes such as `background-color` to read what color the designers set it to in the stylesheet.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks for reading - Jim

Comment: So today's cell will have the `background-color` from the `.calendarToday` class on it, but on `mouseout` you want the `background-color` to change?

Comment: Close, but when I mouse out I want the background color to change back to the original color as set in the style sheet.  As it is written the code uses a Replace to change it to a specific color and I don't know how to read what that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now.  If you want the `background-color` to revert to what is specified in the CSS, you can set it to the empty string, such as `this.style.backgroundColor = ''`.  This will remove the inline style background-color on the cell.

**Demo**

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for (var i = 0, l = cells.length; i < l; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { this.style.backgroundColor = 'goldenrod'; });
  cells[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() { this.style.backgroundColor = ''; });
}
```

```css
.calendar {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.calendar td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.calendarToday {
    background-color: mistyrose;   
}
```

```html
<table class="calendar">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>Wednesday</td>
      <td class="calendarToday">Thursday</td>
      <td>Friday</td>
      <td>Saturday</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How easy is that? (When you know how!)  I'll give it a try when I can get to it and mark answered as it seems like there will be no problems with your solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for the extra effort to make the code example that was very helpful.  Marked answered and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again.